# jQuery animation jumps to top of parent when pressing up or down. Works with right and left

Tags: jquery, animation, key-bindings

I'm trying to make a little fun spaceshooter game. I animated the position of my spaceship, but when I press up or down, it jumps to the top of the parent element. I've noticed that it overwrites the css "bottom"-property when doing so. Does someone know how to fix this?

Here's my code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(key) {
    switch(parseInt(key.which)) {
        case up:
            $('#ship').animate({top: "-=100px"}, '10', 'linear');
            break;

        case down:
            $('#ship').animate({top: "+=100px"}, '10', 'linear');
            break;

        case left:
             $('#ship').animate({left: "-=100px"}, '10', 'linear');
            break;

        case right:
            $('#ship').animate({left: "+=100px"}, '10', 'linear');
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify `top` or `bottom`, but not both as only one can be active at a time.  If you had a `bottom` value and then you set a `top` value, you will not get a smooth movement from where it was because it will animate from the default value of `top` which is `0` to your `100px` less than that which will cause it to immediately jump to `top:0` and then animate from there.

If you are going to initially specify `bottom` and want to animate smoothly from that, then animate the `bottom` value, not the `top` value.

So, either change your initial CSS to use `top` instead of `bottom` or change your code to animate `bottom`.  Be consistent between the two and you won't see the jump when you animate.

Comment: @JensAagren - since it looks like you are new on StackOverflow, do you understand that once your question has been answered, you should select the best answer (click the green checkmark to the left of the answer) to indicate to the community that you have an answer, to reward the person who provided the answer (they earn reputation points) and you too will earn some reputation points for following the proper procedure on StackOverflow?